# Spring security failureUrl being overridden in Heroku environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, heroku

I have a Spring MVC Java app using Spring Security 3.2.9. The app uses Java config for the security configuration, and locally the login/authenticate process works fine.

However, when the application is running in our Heroku dev environment, login failures are not reaching the correct URL. I can see in the logs that a GET call is being made to the correct URL, "/signin?error=1", but an additional call to "/" seems to be hijacking it and redirecting to the home URL "/".

The security config is:

`@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

    .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/signin**", "/resources/**", "/signup").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
            .formLogin()
            .failureUrl("/signin?error=1")
            .loginPage("/signin")
            .permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
    .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/signin")
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
            .key("remember-me-key")
    ;
}`

In the Heroku logs I see a call to "/authenticate", a call to "/signin?error=1", and a call to "/". The order these appear in the log is not consistent, so it's not necessarily a chain of events.

`Jun 11 06:25:54 myapp-dev heroku/router: at=info method=POST path="/authenticate" host=myapp-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=25cfa779-67ab-4bb4-a036-d25ad3e893cb fwd="109.159.48.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=302 bytes=465 protocol=https 
Jun 11 06:25:54 myapp-dev heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/signin?error=1" host=myapp-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=7dcbbc85-2f7a-4acf-94c3-adc8231eb980 fwd="109.159.48.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=302 bytes=171 protocol=http 
Jun 11 06:25:54 myapp-dev heroku/router: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myapp-dev.herokuapp.com request_id=5be5f96c-0e29-4caf-9183-c3976ec19c9b fwd="109.159.48.152" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=6143 protocol=https`

I have logging in my Signin controller and the call is definitely not reaching it. If I just type `/signin?error=1` into the browser, it reaches the controller with no problems.

I've tried adding a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler instead of using `.failureUrl()`. Again, it works fine locally (both on Tomcat running with Eclipse, and also with standalone Spring Boot startup from the command line), but not when the app is deployed.

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong, or an alternative approach which might sidestep the problem?

Comment: For now I've worked around the problem by using a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler to add a session attribute indicating login failure, which is then picked up in the Signin controller.

I'd prefer to understand what's happening and use the normal failureUrl pattern rather than bodging it like this, so any suggestions would still be gratefully received!